# Is Nested Fragment Possible?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-nested-fragment

I have a ViewPager contains three fragment, and I want to put 3 new fragments into the third fragment.Is that possible?

```
[ViewPager]
    [Fragment 1]
    [Fragment 2]
    [Fragment 3]
        [Fragment 3-1]
        [Fragment 3-2]
        [Fragment 3-3]
[ViewPager]
```

EDIT: I can't getChildFragmentManager() but only getFragmentManager(), I'm using android.support.v4.app:

```
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.layout.tools_frame5, new Plugins());
    ft.commit();
```

EDIT:  what about Putting 3 Activities in the third Fragment, Is that possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Nested fragment is possible.

You have to use **getChildFragmentManager()** instead of **getFragmentManager()** while you are working with nested fragments. For more details look into [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager()).

Hope this will help you....:)

Comment: But this is only Added in API level 11, it's not supported in android.support.v4?

Comment: yes it seems to be also supported in the support library http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager()

Comment: and it doesn't appear in API level 11 but API level 17

Comment: EDIT:what about Putting 3 Activities in the third Fragment, Is that possible?