# Dynamically changing Views with functionality in onCreateView

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Currently I have connected activities handled this way, `Activity A --> Activity B--Activity C`. I discovered that I could use nested fragments and contained in one Activity. So I imagined that would be,

```
Main Activity
--Fragment A -> Fragment B -> Fragment C
```

From this code below, I manage to dynamically populate a text for every created fragments. I am just curious on how I could  create fragments and use the flow above with different views.

So my possible resolve is to use `if statements` in one onCreateView to check if which fragment to be displayed. Your thoughts will help me understand the complex concept of dynamic creation of fragments. Thanks

```
    public class CollectionDemoActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide fragments representing
     * each object in a collection. We use a {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}
     * derivative, which will destroy and re-create fragments as needed, saving and restoring their
     * state in the process. This is important to conserve memory and is a best practice when
     * allowing navigation between objects in a potentially large collection.
     */
    DemoCollectionPagerAdapter mDemoCollectionPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.ViewPager} that will display the object collection.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_collection_demo);

        // Create an adapter that when requested, will return a fragment representing an object in
        // the collection.
        // 
        // ViewPager and its adapters use support library fragments, so we must use
        // getSupportFragmentManager.
        mDemoCollectionPagerAdapter = new DemoCollectionPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        // Specify that the Home button should show an "Up" caret, indicating that touching the
        // button will take the user one step up in the application's hierarchy.
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        // Set up the ViewPager, attaching the adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mDemoCollectionPagerAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                // This is called when the Home (Up) button is pressed in the action bar.
                // Create a simple intent that starts the hierarchical parent activity and
                // use NavUtils in the Support Package to ensure proper handling of Up.
                Intent upIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                if (NavUtils.shouldUpRecreateTask(this, upIntent)) {
                    // This activity is not part of the application's task, so create a new task
                    // with a synthesized back stack.
                    TaskStackBuilder.from(this)
                            // If there are ancestor activities, they should be added here.
                            .addNextIntent(upIntent)
                            .startActivities();
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // This activity is part of the application's task, so simply
                    // navigate up to the hierarchical parent activity.
                    NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, upIntent);
                }
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter} that returns a fragment
     * representing an object in the collection.
     */
    public static class DemoCollectionPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        public DemoCollectionPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            Fragment fragment = new DemoObjectFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(DemoObjectFragment.ARG_OBJECT, i + 1); // Our object is just an integer :-P
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // For this contrived example, we have a 100-object collection.
            return 100;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return "OBJECT " + (position + 1);
        }
    }

    /**
     * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply displays dummy text.
     */

    public static class DemoObjectFragment extends Fragment {

        public static final String ARG_OBJECT = "object";

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.load_main_menu_activity, container, false);
            Bundle args = getArguments();
           //((TextView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(
                 //   Integer.toString(args.getInt(ARG_OBJECT)));
            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Fragment is hosted by a activity. You are talking about nested fragment?

Comment: yes, nested fragments inside handled by one activity.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17269187/is-nested-fragment-possible. and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221763/android-can-you-nest-fragments and the docs http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments

Comment: thanks for those links.:) Can you show me sir maybe two fragments one is a child sharing one onCreateView? ^^ been struggling with this for a while now. No relative progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_fragment, container, false);
        Button nextButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_first);
        nextButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code.

```
package com.example.viewpagerexample;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class ViewPagerExample extends FragmentActivity {
    private MyAdapter mAdapter;
    private ViewPager mPager;
    private static Activity activity;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            activity = this;
            mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new Fragment1();
            case 1:
                return new Fragment2();
            case 2:
                return new Fragment3();
            default:
                return new Fragment1();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks sir can you give a small code inside new fragment1(); to display this fragment?