# PlaceAutocompleteFragment not working on Android 5.0 & Up

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, google-places-api

I want to use `PlaceAutocompleteFragment` in My Application.

I successfully Implemented `PlaceAutocompleteFragment` and Its working fine.(In Samsung S4 and HTC Desire).

But When I checked this functionality in **Android 5.0 (Mi4i)** and **Android 5.1.1 (Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1)** and **Android 6.0 (Moto G Turbo)** App is crashed....

I am using below code in `Fragment` which is **implement** `PlaceSelectionListener`.

```
PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment);
autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(this);

@Override
    public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Place selection : " + place.getAddress(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    /**
     * Callback invoked when PlaceAutocompleteFragment encounters an error.
     */
    @Override
    public void onError(Status status) {

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Place selection failed: " + status.getStatusMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

In XML layout file.

```
<fragment
      android:id="@+id/autocomplete_fragment"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**logcat**

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                   Process: com.organization.project, PID: 11635
>                                                                                   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceSelectionListener)'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                                       at
>   com.organization.project.fragments.FragmentSearchPlace.onCreateView(FragmentSearchPlace.java:39)
>                                                                                       at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2053)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:894)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
>                                                                                       at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:839)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1454)
>                                                                                       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:447)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5234)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                       at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:909)
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:704)

Added Below Dependencies in Gradle File.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.1'
compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1"
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.1'
```

Comment: did you find a solution? I have the same problem when updating from `play-services-location:8.x` to 9.x

Answer (score 4):

From your stack trace, it looks like you're using the Autocomplete fragment nested inside another fragment (FragmentSearchPlace). Maybe using [`getChildFragmentManager()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17269263/2994) instead of `getFragmentManager()` would work.

Comment: `Call requires API level 17 (current min is 15): android.app.Fragment#getChildFragmentManager`. But my min sdk is 15. And I want to give support sdk 15 and Up.

Comment: Hey thanks for pointing out for getChildFragmentManager(). Its working fine if I change API level. But I want API level 15. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23640066/getchildfragmentmanager-and-support-libraries

Answer (score 0):

You don't add a fragment into other fragment by the property "name" in your Layout. You must use:

```
autocompleteFragment = new SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();           
transaction.replace(R.id.fragme_autocomplete_destino,autocompleteFragment);
transaction.commit();
```